# How to kill a docker container when it reaches set of memory usage or CPU limit

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a docker container which running in a pod where I need to restart the pod / container when it exceeds memory usage or CPU limit. How to configure it in docker file

Answer (score 2):

CPU and memory limits cannot be given when building a docker and it cannot be configured in `Docker File`. It is a scheduling problem. You could run your docker with `docker run` command with different flags to control resources. See [Docker Official Document](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/) for those control flags for `docker run`.

As your question is tagged with `kubernetes`, there is `kubernetes` way to limit your resources. You would want to add `resources` in specs for those `deployment` or `pod` yaml. For example:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: your_deployment
  labels:
    app: your_app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: your_app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: your_container
        image: your_image
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "500m"
            memory: "128Mi"
          requests:
            cpu: "250m"
            memory: "64Mi"
        ...
```

`requests` affects how docker pod is scheduled on nodes. `Memory limit` determines when the docker will be killed for OOM and `cpu limit` determines how the container cpu usage will be throttled (The pod will not be killed).

Meaning of `cpu` is different for each cloud service providers. For more information, please refer to [manage compute resources for Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/)

Comment: Downvote for the misleading answer. 
"A Container might or might not be allowed to exceed its CPU limit for extended periods of time. However, it will not be killed for excessive CPU usage. "
 Stated by [the official k8s doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#how-pods-with-resource-limits-are-run).

Comment: Moreover, the question asks "How to configure it in docker file?". So please, read the question carefully.

Comment: Thanks @WindyFields for the clarification and suggestions. Will update my answer.